# How can the GP 635T GPS module attached to an Arduino send coordinates to the laptop?

Tags: module, gps, usb, arduino

I am trying to create a space balloon. I need a way to track the balloon. I found a GPS Module with built-in antenna which is the GP-635T. However, after I set it up with the arduino, what is the code or what should I upload to the arduino so that it sends coordinates to the laptop without being connected via USB.

Here is the GPS Module:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11571

Comment: What do you mean by not being connected via USB? Just on the testing phase on your bench or when you let go the ballon on the sky?

Comment: I'm asking how do I program the arduino to send GPS coordinates as it is going up in the sky. I have no idea what program to upload and setup the computer so it receives the gps coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do doesn't involve merely programming the arduino. It will require you a radio or satellite transmitter to send out the coordinates to a matching receiver that can be connected to your PC to demodulate the radio signal and present the coordinate data through USB or serial interfaces. I'm sorry to say that, but unfortunately it seems to be a very expensive proposition and a bit hard for you to implement considering you seem not to know how to program the arduino yet or are aware of the additional hardware requirements and technical difficulties involved.

If you do happen to get a radio or satellite transmitter to go on the ballon and supply it with an adequate battery, the arduino part will be the easiest, just read the coordinate data from the serial port connected to your GPS module and relay it to the other serial port connected to your transmitter. Since you only have one hardware serial port on the arduino you'll have to use a software serial library for the other one.

Answer (score 1):

A common hobbyist method to balloon tracking is to use the cellular phone system. Get a cellular module and have the Arduino text its location to your phone.

This obviously won't work in near-space but it's a cheap, long range system for balloon recovery once it gets closer to the ground. (Provided you are in an area with adequate cell phone service and not in the middle of a desert)